# Having button that runs code, but doesn't submit data to (or validates against) table

Tags: x++, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I'm trying to add a button to an existing form (**BankAccountTable**). I want to add a button to run an outside process with the value of one of the form fields as a parameter.

The value is being read using this code:

`str value = element.design().controlName("FieldName").valueStr();`

However when I click the button Dynamics displays what fields must be filled in. This doesn't happen if the click method doesn't reference the form fields (i.e. `info("click");`).

How can I:

- Read the value of a field without triggering form validation?

and/or

- Have a button (or command buttton) that doesn't trigger form validation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second question, how to avoid validation, is easy: set the button attribute `SaveRecord` to `No`.

You should rarely need to access the control value directly. A better option is usually to access the bound field directly:  `table.FieldName`.

If the control is not bound to a field, then change the `AutoDeclation` attribute to `Yes` and access the control directly: `fieldName.text()`. The methods `text`, `realValue` or `selection` is a better choice than `valueStr`.